# signOut() does not work after i navigate to a screen..but it works when i do not navigate.. how can i fix this?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

I have two pages in my app which are shown after the sign in process, Home() and Edit(). Edit() page can be accessed through the bottom navigation bar in Home() page. In the edit page ,user can press 'OK' after editing. When the user presses "OK", the screen changes to Home() page, where the changes are shown. Once this process is done, the signOut() button in the Home() page does not work. If the user does not press "OK " in Edit() page after sign in process, the signOut() button works alright. How can i fix this?

The onPressed() {} for the "OK " is shown below.

```
onPressed() {
  // also the form data saving to database.
 Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
}
```

Comment: provide the `signOut()` method

Comment: Its the firebase auth built in signOut() method. It works perfectly if I do not use the Navigator.popAndPushNamed(). So i think it has something to do with the route.

Comment: what is the value of `HomeScreen.id`??

Comment: i set the route of the HomeScreen.id: (context) => HomeScreen(), in main.dart..if thats what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should as the following:

```
        onPressed: () {
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        auth.signOut().then((res) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()),
            );
        });
        },
```

Here `onPressed` of the `signOut` button, the user signs out of firebase thus there will be no current user and you will navigate to a different page.

Comment: Thank you Peter. This is working alright and my previous signOut() is also working and it brings the user to signIn() screen. However, when the user signs in , user is shown the home() page where there is a bottom navigation bar..where the user can tap on the edit icon to go to the Edit() page. Now when the user is done editing  and clicks the "OK " button that has onPressed() { Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);} . that takes user back to home() page. After this the signOut() button does not work.

Comment: If I remove  Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id); from the onPressed(){} of "OK", then the signOut() is still working. The function you gave above for signOut() is working and takes the user to signIn() page but after that the other button on SignIn() page does not work. Is there any other workaround to take the user to Home() page through the onPressed of the "Ok"  button that i mentioned in the question?

Comment: In the code that you added to the question, on press you are going to the home screen. I don't see any reason for the signout button in the home screen not to work if you use my code...

Comment: When you use `popAndPushNamed` then `home` screen is the root router https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popAndPushNamed.html if you signout, you have to go somewhere.. so probably dont use `popAndPushNamed`

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that..your code is working for the signOut() and it does signOut  the signed in user. But after that if i SignIn() again on the same page..then it keeps on loading..also there is a register() page button on the signIn() page..so this ''register'' button does not work after i use your code to SignOut(). The register button works alright and takes user to the register page if i do not use your SignOut() code above.

Comment: I did not add the code here because it is like 10 pages . But i added your code at the right place and it is working alright. Thank you Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to prevent the sign in again problem:

```
OutlinedButton(onPressed: () async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    if (!mounted) return;
    Navigator.pop(context);
   }, child: const Text('Sign out')),
```

Also it is recommended to add firebase auth listener at main.dart to navigate user based on auth state.

Comment: Make sure to convert the widget from stateless to stateful, since (!mounted) work only with stateful widget.